# wordpress wp_get_archives(); not working

Tags: php, wordpress

i used wp_get_archives() but it didn't show anything.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( 
array( 
        'post_type' => 'wordpress',
        'posts_per_page' => 10000,
)
);　
wp_get_archives();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();



include("index-loop.php");

endwhile; ?>
```

How should I show archives?

Comment: what you mean by post type `wordpress` ?

Comment: It' the post type's name of a custom post type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This ,

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archives
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main">
        <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
    <ul>
         <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

you can get more information from [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index)

and function info get from [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

Comment: Thanks.My template is custom-post-type.In custom post type, wp_get_archives cannot be used without editing the functions.php.I defined a function and wp_get_archives worked.